# React native signed APK crash

Tags: react-native, crash, apk, signed

Signed APK crash after launch, in logCat i got `requiring unknown module 'React'`

Debug application works fine, but in logCat i got >> Requiring module 'React' by name is only supported for debugging purposes and will BREAK IN PRODUCTION!

React v15.4.1, React native v0.39.2 ?

Sorry for my english

Comment: How does react imported in your code? (for ex `import React from "react"`)

Comment: import React, { Component } from "react"

Comment: Probably you should not use 'React' as name for the module (it is a haste module name, used internally by facebook), try `import React from "react"`

Comment: It was a mistake I corrected it but always the same thing

Comment: Is signed app call component by id ?

Comment: I can suggest to post some code that shows exact problem.

Comment: Can you try to add debugger or console.log to print out where did your application crash?

Answer (score 0):

this is my index.android.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';

import myapp from './index_start.js';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => myapp);
```

and index_start.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {
      StyleSheet,
      AppRegistry,
      Text,
      Image,
      View,
      AsyncStorage,
      NetInfo,
      StatusBar,
      Navigator,
      Dimensions
    } from 'react-native';

    // Window dismensions
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

    // Device infos
    import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
    // Native SplashScreen
    import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
    // Spinner
    import Spinner from 'react-native-spinkit';

    // Models
    import User from './model/UserModel';
    // Json data for initial launch
    var DB = require('./DB.json');

    // Components
    import Stage from './components/stage/stage.js'
    import Player from './components/player/player.js'
    import Settings from './components/settings/settings.js'
    import House from './stages/house/house.js'


    // LocalStorage key
    var USER_KEY = 'user_key';

    const routes = [
        {name: 'loading'},
        {name: 'stage', component: Stage},
        {name: 'house', component: House},
        {name: 'settings', component: Settings}
    ];

    const _navigator = null;

    export default class myapp extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                isConnected: false,
                isLoading: true,
                _navigator: null,
                stages: null
            }
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            // check if connected
            this._checkConnexionType();
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            SplashScreen.hide();

            this._loadInitialData();
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
            // console.log(this.state.stages)

            if (!this.state.isLoading && this.state.stages !== null) {
                _navigator.push({
                    name: 'stage',
                    passProps: {
                        data: this.state.stages
                    }
                })
            }
        }

        /**
        * Load localStorage Data
        */
        async _loadInitialData() {
            // GET User LocalStorage

            if (this.state.stages == null) {

                var localData;
                //AsyncStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY)

                AsyncStorage.getItem(USER_KEY).then((data) => {
                    if (data !== null) {
                        var localData = JSON.parse(data);
                        // User.uuid = localData.uuid;
                        User.setStages(localData.stages)

                        this.setState({
                            'stages' : localData.stages
                        })
                    } else {
                        var storage = {};
                        storage.setUiid = DeviceInfo.getUniqueID();
                        storage.stages = DB.stages;
                        AsyncStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(storage));

                        this.setState({
                            'stages' : DB.stages
                        })
                    }

                })

            }

            if (this.state.isConnected) {
                // var rStages = this._loadRemoteStages();
                // console.log(rStages);
            }

            // Change state
            setTimeout((function() {
                this.setState({
                    'isLoading': false
                })
            }).bind(this), 1500);

        }


        /**
        * GET stages from remote DB
        */
        async _loadRemoteStages() {
            await fetch(API_URL)
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    console.log(responseJson)
                    return responseJson;
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }

        /**
        * CHECK IF user is connected to Network
        * SET bool to state isLoading
        */
        _checkConnexionType() {
            NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(response => {
              this.setState({ isConnected: response})
            })
        }

        _renderScene(route, navigator) {

            _navigator = navigator;

            if (route.name == 'loading') {
                return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
                        <Image
                            style={{width: width, height: height}}
                            source={require('./img/screen.jpg')}
                        />

                        <View style={styles.loading}>
                          <Text style={styles.loadingText}>CHARGEMENT</Text>
                          <Spinner type="ThreeBounce" color={'#fff'}/>
                        </View>

                    </View>
                )
            } else if (route.name == 'stage') {
                return (
                    <Stage navigator={_navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
                )
            } else if (route.name == 'player') {
                return (
                    <House navigator={_navigator} {...route.passProps}}/>
                )
            } else if (route.name == 'settings') {
                return (
                    <Settings navigator={_navigator} {...route.passProps}/>
                )
            }
        }

        render() {

            return (

                <Navigator
                    initialRoute={{name: 'loading'}}
                    configureScene={() => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottomAndroid}
                    renderScene={this._renderScene.bind(this)}
                />


            );
        }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      loading: {
          flex: 1,
          position: 'absolute',
          bottom: 50,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          alignItems: 'center',
      },
      loadingText:{
          flex: 1,
          fontFamily: 'CarterOne',
          fontSize: 20,
          color: '#fff'
      }
    });
```